# Taylor series with integration

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am having trouble with this problem. I have used taylor series but dont know what to do next to proof that S = 1;
[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use the convergence and divergence tests to do this problem as well.

Comment: What if you set $x=1$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set the integral interval to be $[0,1]$. It is easy to see that the right side is $\Sigma \frac{1}{n!(n+2)}$.

On the other hand $$\int_0^1 xe^xdx=1.$$

Here you are!